# How do I export the headlines of all the blog posts in a single category?

Tags: categories, export

I need a list of all the blog post I wrote on a topic. (Basically a list of headlines that are marked with a certain category.)

One of my readers once created a list like this and emailed it to me, but I never asked him how he did it and can't find his email.

Comment: Do you have access to phpMyAdmin for your database?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [new page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates), and in that template put:

```
<?php wp_get_archives('type=postbypost'); ?>
```

This will list every one of your posts by post date.

(Reference: [wp_get_archives](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives))